# Mouse scroll stuck while cursor is on top of youtube_player_iframe

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, youtube-player-flutter

Mouse scroll stuck on top of video. I'm using [youtube_player_iframe](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_iframe). Also, I don't want to rebuild the iframe widget. I tried to wrap it with `pointer_interceptor` but it didn't solve the problem. My first priority is to solve the scroll issue and avoid rebuilding the widget on scrolling. Wrapping everything on `SingleChildScrollView` is not a good practice.

- I don't want to use YouTube API like this package
- Need to implemented **flutter-web**

if you have an alternative way to handle it, feel free to share.
Thanks

check this output [video](https://github.com/yeasin50/AssetsFor_/blob/master/temp/scroll_issue_withifremyt_player_Trim.mp4?raw=true)

**Test widget**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pointer_interceptor/pointer_interceptor.dart';
import 'package:sliver_tools/sliver_tools.dart';

import 'package:youtube_player_iframe/youtube_player_iframe.dart';

class YoutubeVideoAdTestScreen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  YoutubeVideoAdTestScreen2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _YoutubeVideoAdTestScreen2State createState() =>
      _YoutubeVideoAdTestScreen2State();
}

class _YoutubeVideoAdTestScreen2State extends State<YoutubeVideoAdTestScreen2> {
  YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
    initialVideoId: '1oF3pI5umck',
    params: YoutubePlayerParams(
      // Defining custom playlist
      startAt: Duration(seconds: 30),
      showControls: true,
      showFullscreenButton: true,
    ),
  );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.close();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          MultiSliver(
            children: [
              ...List.generate(
                4,
                (index) => Container(
                  color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.amber : Colors.cyanAccent,
                  height: index * 50 + 100,
                ),
              ).toList(),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: YoutubePlayerIFrame(
                  gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{},
                  controller: _controller,
                  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                ),
              ),
              ...List.generate(
                4,
                (index) => Container(
                  color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.amber : Colors.cyanAccent,
                  height: index * 50 + 100,
                ),
              ).toList(),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I used thumbnails on body and played the video on dialog just to overcome this situation.  You can check [this](https://github.com/yeasin50/lisa_fischer/blob/master/lib/widgets/widget.ytVideoWrapperForScrollIssue.dart#L11)

Answer (score 5):

The Problem with embedding HTML elements in your Flutter App is, that these are rendered differently. The dart api provides this information about `iframes` and their `pointer events`:

> Due to security restrictions with cross-origin `iframe` elements, Flutter **cannot dispatch pointer events** to an HTML view. If an `iframe` is the target of an event, the window containing the  is not notified of the event. In particular, this means that any pointer events which land on an `iframe` will not be seen by Flutter, and so the HTML view **cannot participate in gesture detection with other widgets**.

There is no ideal solution to this, either losing the ability to scroll when hovering the `iframe`, or to lose the ability to interact with the  `iframe`, but still scroll over it.

The idea is simple: Wrap another `AspectRatio` in a `PointerInterceptor`, inside a `Stack`, so that the scrolling behaviour is still provided, but you sadly cannot interact with the `iframe` any more.

```
.....
SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      YoutubePlayerIFrame(
        gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{},
        controller: _controller,
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      ),
      PointerInterceptor(
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
......
```

There are surely different ways to implement this, butI found this to be the easiest if you just want to scroll over the `iframe`. The player can still be controlled via its `_controller`, so `play()`, `stop()` etc. still seem to work.

**EDIT**:
The `PointerInterceptor` is a pub.dev package: https://pub.dev/packages/pointer_interceptor

Comment: At this point, it totally ignores the click event.